# WSO2AM - Starting very slow

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm having issues with the startup time of wso2am. I'm not sure why but it is taking too long on startup. We have configured it with HA (2 nodes) and all databases are in Postgres. WSO2AM version is 3.1.0.

After we changed the jvm parameters (basically memory) it cames very very slow, sometimes it takes more than 15 minutes to start when it usually took 1 minute.
I can share an extract of the log if you want or some other properties. It takes most of time starting webapps as you can see below

```
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:21:58,577]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} - Starting polling event receivers
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:22:19,636]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:22:19,683]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.
admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
TID: [-1234] [accountrecoveryendpoint] [2020-07-21 11:22:28,154]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/accountrecoveryendpoint]
.File[/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/accountrecoveryendpoint]
TID: [-1234] [am#sample#calculator#v1] [2020-07-21 11:22:44,955]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/am/sample/calculator/v1]
.File[/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/am#sample#calculator#v1.war]
TID: [-1234] [am#sample#pizzashack#v1] [2020-07-21 11:23:01,998]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/am/sample/pizzashack/v1]
.File[/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/am#sample#pizzashack#v1.war]
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:23:19,636]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:23:19,683]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.
admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
TID: [-1234] [api#am#admin#v0.16] [2020-07-21 11:23:35,489]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/admin/v0.16].File[/opt
/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#admin#v0.16.war]
TID: [-1234] [api#am#publisher#v0.16] [2020-07-21 11:24:00,190]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/publisher/v0.16].F
ile[/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#publisher#v0.16.war]
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:24:19,636]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:24:19,684]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
TID: [-1234] [api#am#publisher] [2020-07-21 11:24:38,287]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/publisher].File[/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#publisher.war]
TID: [-1234] [api#am#store#v0.16] [2020-07-21 11:25:02,324]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} - Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/store/v0.16].File[/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server/webapps/api#am#store#v0.16.war]
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:25:19,636]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
TID: [-1] [] [2020-07-21 11:25:19,684]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
```

Sorry that I do not have more information but I'm completely lost on what to check.

Thanks!

Comment: You can take a thread dump to analyze this.. Where are running this setup? Is it AWS? What is the file sharing mechanism you have used in the deployment? What are the memory values you changed?

Comment: and what's your OS?

Comment: Hello! We are running it on AWS in a t3xlarge instance. We use NFS for file shared mechanism between nodes and we just configured Xms and Xmx values on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the root cause.
We have implemented it on AWS using EFS to share deployment/server directory to accomplish WSO2AM HA Requirements.
Due to type of throughput configured on the EFS(Bursting mode) it is limiting the IO so the startup take too much. The maximum IO provisioned was 4KiB(Bursting mode has a relation between IO and how much space you use).

Our solution was create a new instance, configure NFS service inside and solved from that way. Also you can configure EFS as Provisioned throughput mode, but it was so expensive for us.